# Why do my side loaded apps stop working after a few days?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I am actually kind of new to iOS development. However, I have made a few apps after being taught how. But one thing I have noticed is that if I use my phone to test my app, the app will run when its plugged in and maybe a day or two afterwards, but after that time, it stops working and crashes if I try to open it, like when I want to show someone my app or just use it in general. The only way to get it to work again is by running the app through Xcode again and its fine for another 2 days. Is this normal?

I have noticed that the "developer" setting in the settings app on my phone has disappeared, would that have something to do with my "side loaded" apps crashing?

Comment: This sounds like a code signing issue. Are you on a free developer account, or have you paid Apple the $100 for a full one this year?

Comment: I have the free one. I haven't paid anything because I haven't released anything yet. Should I be paying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Upgrade to a paid account for a longer codesigning lifetime, otherwise you'll need to keep recompiling/reinstalling your app every few days

When installing an app to your phone, Xcode signs your app with your developer certificate. Signatures for free tier certificates expire after a few days, and iOS will refuse to launch your app if it has an expired signature. When the free program was started, the lifetime of free certificate signatures was well-defined as a week, though I'm having trouble finding a hard number right now, so it very well may've been lowered to a couple days. Regardless, the $99/year paid-tier certificates can install your apps on your devices for up to a year before they expire. If you'd like your apps to last longer on your phone, you'll need to upgrade to a paid account

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I appreciate it. I will look into paying for the membership soon.